# how to create a mesh collider for a procedurally generated landscape mesh in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, procedural-generation

I'm currently working in unity 3d following a tutorial by Sabastian League and I got the mesh working but I cant add a collider to make it so my player lands on top of and is able to walk around on the mesh

I tried making the mesh generate the collider in the code and adding one manually by using a mesh collider and setting the mesh to the terrain but it wont work still

Comment: When you add the MeshCollider to a mesh, Unity automatically generates the collider based on the mesh. What does it mean "won't work"? Do you see the green "outline" in the editor's view indicating the collider?

Comment: i do not have the green outline in the editor view but it dose show up in when I change the mode to convex  i even dropped a cube right on the middle of it and it fell trough it so there is not collider at all@h4ri

Comment: Can you share some screenshots? Mesh collider should work.